# CSS How to make text to scale like an image

Tags: html, css, text, responsive-design, responsive

I cannot figure out how to make text behave like image when resized. When I'm resizing browser text stays as large as on the beginning and starts to break in many rows. I tried to experiment with VW font-size but in that case, the text was too large on big screen and too small on small screen.

There are my css classes:

```
.text_head_container{
  font-size: 35px;
  font-size: 2.1875rem;
  color: white;
  width:60%;
  display:inline-block;

}    
.img_head_container{
  display:inline-block;
  width:15%;
  height:auto;
}
```

I'll be thankful for any help with this.

Regards.

Comment: I dont think this is possible in pure css which is why libraries like http://fittextjs.com/ exist

Comment: If you want a CSS only solution where the text resize when browser resize, viewport units like `vh` and `vw` is what's available, or else script will be necessary.

Comment: I updated my answer to use the vmin + vmax, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that media queries is the only reasonable option here:

```
p {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  p {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You said you have already tried vw. Have you tried it this way?
[Responsive Text](http://codepen.io/Ballard/pen/WGpxZW)
I set the vmin and vmax on the text, This way it won't go below the minimum vw that you set, nor should it go above the max height, and it is still completely responsive.

```css
.resize{
  font-size: 35px;
  font-size: 6vmax;
  font-size; 1vmin;
  width:60%;
  display:inline-block;

}    
.text{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">
  <p class="text"> Just some random text, Just some random text,  Just some random text, Just some random text,  Just some random text, Just some random text, Just some random text, Just some random text, </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not resize text when the window resize's, read the question

Comment: Ignore the snippet and click on the codepen that is linked, resize the browser and you will see.

Comment: I was very close but still I had to use @media. Thank you for help and showing me vmin and vmax :)

Answer (score 1):

CSS does not easily offer the facilities you'd need to make the size of the font scale non-linearly with the size of the browser.  `vw` is the closest you're going to get simply, and if you feel that it's too large on a large screen and too small on a small screen, you're going to have to do a bit of lifting.

What I would recommend you do is to start by figuring out what the right sizes are every 800px from 600px up to 2k, then again at 3k and 4k, and to find a function that fits the curve you build.  Something like "at 800px I want 26px, at 1000px I want 29px," etc, should be all you need.  Then any random [curve fit](https://mycurvefit.com/)ter should be able to give you the relevant function.

Once you have that function, you have, basically, two options.

1. Implement your curve with `calc()` (not always possible, and loses a lot of browser fallback)
2. Make a huge list of media queries with small steps, and fonts defined inbetween them (generatable, but ... ew)
3. Listen for the document resize event, and reassign font size following (either directly or by overwriting some CSS-DOM rule, the latter of which is what most plugins for this do)

Here's a [simple implementation of listening for the document resize event](http://www.dotticontra.org/devel/javascript/jquery_dynamic_font_resize.html).